# Swift analogue of Java Thread.join()

Tags: java, ios, swift, multithreading

That is how my code looks right now. I am trying to launch a thread but my code goes to recursive cycle. I would like to get my error reason from you or get Swift analogue of wonderful Java Thread.join() function which is very useful in this situation.

```
var ret: JSON = JSON("{\"code\":\"-3\"}")
        var cont: Bool = true

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        let req = Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://pornhub.com", parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                print("TEST: " + ret.string!)
                ret = json
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("TEST: " + ret.string!)
                ret = (JSON("{\"code\":\"-2\"}"))
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            cont = false

        })

    })

    while(cont) {
        sleep(1)
    }

    return ret
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are blocking the main thread anyway why even use `async` in this case?

If you do want to not block the main thread (usually the UI thread and usually a very bad idea to do) you should call the method you provided in code and pass in a "completion" block.  That completion block will have the `ret` value and will allow your process to continue.  It may be a little difficult to see with that explanation, so I'll try to explain it with pseudo code:

```
function mainThread()
{
    var somethingINeed = firstAttempt()
    doSomethingWithReturn(somethingINeed);
}

function firstAttempt()
{
    var ret = doSomethingLong()
    return ret
}
```

So that just block the main thread and does your long task.  Instead of that, and instead of your async with blocking, try something like this (again, pseudo code):

```
function mainThread()
{
    secondAttempt(method(var ret)
    {
        doSomethingWithReturn(ret);
    })
}

function secondAttempt(functionBlock)
{
    async{
        var ret = doSomethingLong()
        functionBlock(ret)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should do it:

```
func post(parameters: [String : AnyObject], handler: Result<JSON, NSError> -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://hehe.com", parameters: parameters)
        .validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let jsonObject):
            let json = JSON(jsonObject)
            handler(.Success(json))
        case .Failure(let error):
            handler(.Failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
post(["some" : "parameters"]) { response in
    // The following part is called asynchronously, therefore you need to wrap UI updates in a dispatch main block:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        switch response {
        case .Success(let json):
            print(json) // Update your UI with the json here
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error) // Update your UI with an error here
        }
    }
}
```